# Converting to and from octal in Perl 6

Tags: raku

If we have an octal number, e.g. `0o157`, Perl 6 can convert it into decimal:

```perl6
> 0o157
111
```

We are not permitted to remove this `o` in its octal representation:

```perl6
> 0157
Potential difficulties:
    Leading 0 has no meaning. If you meant to create an octal number, use '0o' prefix; like, '0o157'. If you meant to create a string, please add quotation marks.
    ------> 0157⏏<EOL>
```

Now let's make a reverse conversion, from decimal [to octal](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#sub_sprintf):

```perl6
> printf "%#o\n", 111
0157
```

The question is: why is there now no `o` after `0` in the octal representation?

Meanwhile, if we convert to hexadecimal, the `x` will be there:

```perl6
> printf "%#x\n", 111
0x6f
```

Comment: Simple answer: somethings have just slipped through the cracks.

Comment: @BradGilbert Sorry, don't understand. :)

Comment: That was likely implemented early; before it was decided how an octal literal would be written.

Comment: @BradGilbert I see, thanks! I was sure I couldn't understand something important. :)

Comment: @BradGilbert Moritz explains in his answer that it isn't a bug.

Comment: I have a tab opened to [the Perl 6 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl6?sort=active&pageSize=50) 24/7 so I already knew that.

Comment: Hi Eugene. Do you know about `foo.base: 8` and `:8(bar)`?

Comment: Hi @raiph. I know about the 1st but the 2nd doesn't work with me. Could you give an example?

Comment: `say :8('157')` displays `111`.

Comment: @raiph thanks, I didn't put the `' '`. :) Though I don't understand why they are needed here.

Comment: @Eugene I'm not sure what drove the decision to require a string. Maybe ask on #perl6? Underlying such decisions is the choice between [weak and strong typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing). Functions built into P6 use weaker typing (because it just [DWIMs](https://www.google.com/search?q=dwim)) unless there's good reason to use stronger typing for that particular built in function. Someone must have concluded that `:8(bar)` and similar should strongly type `bar` as a string. NB. You can always write `:8<157>` if you don't like the extra two characters in `:8('157')`.

Comment: @raiph It looks analogous to hashes (8, so maybe that's the reason it takes strings as arguments? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The question is: why is there now no `o` after `0` in the octal representation?

(s)printf is a pretty universally used function, and ported directly to Perl 6. It is meant to be compatible with other languages' `printf` functions more than with Perl 6 input syntax.

Perl 5's `printf` behaves the same way, so its behavior was likely copied directly.